# How to redirect psycopg2 copy_expert() output to a variable?

Tags: python, stdout, psycopg2

I would like to process the csv data of a table instead of writing it to a file. How can I redirect psycopg2 [`copy_expert()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert) into a variable, somewhat like this:

```
var1 = cur.copy_expert("COPY test TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER", sys.stdout)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of redirecting `sys.stdout` to a variable, it's easier to replace `sys.stdout` directly:

```
text_stream = io.StringIO()
cur.copy_expert("COPY test TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER", text_stream)
var1 = text_stream.getvalue()
```

This works because `io.StringIO` returns a [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object), which `copy_expert` expects for the second argument.

Comment: How do you read from the text stream line by line? `text_stream.readlines()` doesn't seem to work

Comment: I answered my own question. The seek was in the wrong position - It had been left at the end of the file because of the write operation, so we needed to reset the seek to the beginning of the stream in order to read it. Use `text_stream.seek(0)` before attempting `for line in text_stream.readlines(): ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily redirect sys.stdout to a string in Python 3.4.

**contextlib.redirect_stdout(new_target)**

> Context manager for temporarily redirecting sys.stdout to another file
>   or file-like object.
>
> This tool adds flexibility to existing functions or classes whose
>   output is hardwired to stdout.
>
> For example, the output of help() normally is sent to sys.stdout. You
>   can capture that output in a string by redirecting the output to a
>   io.StringIO object:
>
> ```
> f = io.StringIO() 
> with redirect_stdout(f):
>     help(pow) 
> s = f.getvalue()
> ```

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout